# Super slow deployment using sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx

When I deploy code it takes forever.  I get a completed progress bar within seconds.

```
trr sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath /Users/mark/projects/trr/force-app/main/default/classes                 
*** Deploying v52.0 metadata with SOAP API v53.0 connection ***
Deploy ID: 0AfC1000000p5DlKAI
DEPLOY PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 6/6 Components
```

But then it takes 5-10 minutes for the process to finish show me this:

```
=== Deployed Source
FULL NAME              TYPE       PROJECT PATH
─────────────────────  ─────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
LeadTriggerTest        ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/LeadTriggerTest.cls
LeadTriggerTest        ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/LeadTriggerTest.cls-meta.xml
LeadTriggerTest2       ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/LeadTriggerTest2.cls
LeadTriggerTest2       ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/LeadTriggerTest2.cls-meta.xml
LeadTriggerTest3       ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/LeadTriggerTest3.cls
LeadTriggerTest3       ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/LeadTriggerTest3.cls-meta.xml
LeadTriggerTest4       ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/LeadTriggerTest4.cls
LeadTriggerTest4       ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/LeadTriggerTest4.cls-meta.xml
TriggerManagerHandler  ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/TriggerManagerHandler.cls
TriggerManagerHandler  ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/TriggerManagerHandler.cls-meta.xml
leadTriggerHandler     ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/leadTriggerHandler.cls
leadTriggerHandler     ApexClass  force-app/main/default/classes/leadTriggerHandler.cls-meta.xml
```

For what it's worth, I'm running on a Mac.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Any solution ideas?  This doesn't happen all the time. Deploys start off fast, but get slower and slower as time goes on.

Comment: possible due to the source tracking, which is done after deployment.

Comment: thanks @glls, but I have source tracking turned off.

Comment: today even our org faced this around afternoon (IST), but now its working fine. It took around 46 minutes to retrieve one flow, tried with ANT migration tool, but same result.

Comment: Nagendra Singh - does this issue happen frequently?

Comment: Salesforce sandboxes seem a little slow in the week(s) before a new release, might be that.

Comment: Check the status of your instance server. Performance degradation were reported on some instances yesterday, e.g [CS174](http://status.salesforce.com/instances/CS174/history)